# Pass argument to method

Tags: php, laravel

I have functions that I use in my `Article` model, they add likes to cookies for a specific article and record the time

```
public static function hasLikedToday($articleId, string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        // Check if there are any likes for this article
        if (! array_key_exists($articleId, $articleLikes)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check if there are any likes with the given type
        if (! array_key_exists($type, $articleLikes[$articleId])) {
            return false;
        }

        $likeDatetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $articleLikes[$articleId][$type]);

        return ! $likeDatetime->addDay()->lt(now());
    }

    public static function setLikeCookie($articleId, string $type)
    {
        // Initialize the cookie default
        $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '[]');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        // Update the selected articles type
        $articleLikes[$articleId][$type] = today()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $articleLikesJson = json_encode($articleLikes);

        return cookie()->forever('article_likes', $articleLikesJson);
    }
```

The `php.blade` page itself has buttons

```
<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}/like?type=heart" class="btn btn-primary">Like Heart</a>
<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}/like?type=finger" class="btn btn-primary">Like Finger</a>
```

Here are the routes `web.php`

```
Route::get('/article', function () {
    $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

    return view('article')->with([
        'articleLikesJson' => $articleLikesJson,
    ]);
});

Route::get('article/{id}/like', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@postLike');
```

And the `postLike()` function itself in the `controller`

```
public function postLike($id) {
        $article = Article::find($id);

        $like = request('like');
      
        if ($article->hasLikedToday($article->id, $like)) {
            return response()
                ->json([
                    'message' => 'You have already liked the Article #'.$article->id.' with '.$like.'.',
                ]);
        }
    
        $cookie = $article->setLikeCookie($article->id, $like);
      
        $article->increment('like_{$like}');
    
        return response()
            ->json([
                'message' => 'Liked the Article #'.$article->id.' with '.$like.'.',
                'cookie_json' => $cookie->getValue(),
            ])
            ->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

In general, what is the problem, I have 2 types of likes that can be seen in `php.blade`, and the problem is to pass the choice of the type of like to the `postLike()` function, if in my function instead of `$like` I write `'heart'`, then everything will be work, but I need to determine which type we choose (heart or finger), tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel's Request object.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#input

Like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function postLike($id, Request $request)
{
    $type = $request->input('type');
}
```

Comment: great, thank you)